# builder in FutureBuilder doesn't work in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I call this function but i don't print any things in builder: (context, snapshot){}
I use snapshot.error but doesn't any thing.

```
static Widget fetch() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<ClasssAlbums>>(
      future: WebServices.classs(idt),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
        print(snapshot.error);
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          names = new List();
          ids = new List();
          print('open');
          List<ClasssAlbums> listpis =  snapshot.data.toList();
          names = listpis.map((e) => e.name).toList();
          ids = listpis.map((e) => e.id).toList();
          return Classs() ;
        }
        return Center(child: Text('class is null'),);
      },
    );
  }
```

What do i do?

Comment: Did 'open' has been printed?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to learn how to debug the code using breakpoints , it will be easier for you to check the data returned by the future, and it will saves you time